# What is the time complexity of this reverse string function?

Tags: python, algorithm, reverse

I came across this reverse string function:

```
l = [4,2,1,3,5]

def recReverseString(s):
    print('*')
    l = len(s)
    if l < 2:
        return s
    return recReverseString(s[int(l/2):]) + recReverseString(s[:int(l/2)])

l2 = recReverseString(l)
print(l2)
```

It prints:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
[5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

I prints 9 stars. So, I guess despite the halving operation, the time complexity is still O(n) and not O(log n), which is usually the case with most divide and conquer approaches. Am I right with this?

Comment: If may halve the operations, but each call produces two recursion branches.

Comment: In fact, it is O(nlogn) because slicing is an O(n) operation.

Comment: You are just counting the number of recursive calls, that is a factor of the complexity of the algorithm but not the single one.  You may not ignore the complexity of cutting strings, merging strings...

Comment: `int(l/2)` should be replaced by `l // 2`. `//` is integer division, and `/` is floating-point division. Using floating-point division then converting to `int` is not a particularly good idea.

Comment: "usually the case with most divide and conquer approaches": not at all. In most cases, the divide step is at least O(n). By the way, reversing a string is certainly Ω(n), as all characters must move.

Answer (score 1):

Let T(n) represent the time complexity for the recReverseString function. Then we have the following equation

```
  // Assuming len(s) is O(1) but slicing would be O(n)
  T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)
```

The solution for this equation is O(nlogn).

Take binary search as an example for a divide and conquer algorithm. In binary search the recursive call takes one half of the array. Hence the recursive equation in that case is

```
  T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
```

The solution for this equation is O(logn)

Comment: Why are you _"Assuming len(s) and other operations are O(1)"_?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur He assume that, but it clearly depends on the implementation of these operations.

Comment: Right @Jean-BaptisteYunès. 

In python it is O(1) as the size is stored as a separate variable along with the string

Comment: `len(s)` is O(1). But `s+t` is not. Neither are `s[k:]` and `s[:k]`. Both of those are related to the length of the operands.

Comment: Oh right I missed that part

Answer (score 1):

We may as well assume that the length of the initial sequence is to the nth power of 2. Considering that `len` is O(1) and both twice slicing and connect two lists are O(n), we can list such an equation:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)        (1)
```

Replace n with n/2, we can get:

```
T(n/2) = 2T(n/4) + O(n/2)    (2)
```

After logn times of replacement, we can get:

```
T(2) = 2T(1) + O(1)          (3)
```

Substituting equation 2 into equation 1, we have:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 2O(n/2) + O(n) = 4T(n/4) + 2O(n)
```

Substituting logn times repeatedly until equation 3, and the following can be obtained:

```
T(n) = nT(1) + logn * O(n) = O(n) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn)
```

So the time complexity of your method is `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cut in half at each recursive steps, but for half part you call the function, thus one call ==> two sub-calls.

No, *divide and conquer* has no complexity *per se* (or at least O(n)), it depend on what you make after dividing in parts... You can read [divide and conquer](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/divide-and-conquer-algorithms/) or [analysis of time complexity](https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/time-complexity-analysis-of-recursion-in-programming), read carefully the section about Master Theorem. What has complexity O(log(n)) is the binary search if the trees are somehow balanced. What is log(n) is the maximum height of the stack of the recursive calls.